# Difficulty getting "Universal USB Installer" to work in WINE

Tags: linux, usb, wine

I have a 16 GB USB flash drive inserted into a machine running Linux Mint.

I want to use the Windows program [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) via Wine (the end goal here is to create a XenServer bootable USB drive as described [here](http://blog.citrix24.com/install-xenserver-6-usb-stick/), but that's not relevant to this question).

Currently this is the status of my USB flash drive with `fdisk`:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0 GB, 16008609792 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 15267 cylinders, total 31266816 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e2ab6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    31266815    15632384    b  W95 FAT32
```

So everything appears to be fine, but when I load up *Universal USB Installer* with WINE, it **doesn't detect my USB drive**:

[image]

I edited the image to remove the username, but as you can see, the USB drive is not shown.

So I ran `wincfg` to see if I could manually assign the drive...

[image]

<sup>(The image has been edited to remove the user's name.)</sup>

It looks like Wine is successfully detecting my USB drive (the */media/$USER/87F1-4491*), **why doesn't Universal USB Installer see my USB device?**

Also: I know that a bootable USB can simply be made using `dd`; however, for some reason which is currently beyond my understanding, this doesn't seem to actually work in practice with the XenServer ISO.  This seems to be a known issue, as the XenServer blog specifically recommends using Universal USB Installer.  I tried using `dd` with the XenServer ISO, and it doesn't boot. (I have used `dd` many times with other bootable ISO files successfully, but for some mysterious reason it doesn't work for XenServer.)

Comment: Try to set manually the path to the device. First, mount it, then you use the `/mount/<dev>` or `/dev/<dev>` path to access the filesystem. Then you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Wine supports USB flash drives. To mount a USB flash drive so that Wine can use it, follow these steps:

1. Run `winecfg`
2. Select the *Drives* tab.
3. Click *Add...*
4. Choose a letter for the drive.
5. Click the *Browse...* button next to where it says *Path:*
6. Use the `mount` command to find wherever your operating system has mounted the USB flash drive. Insert your USB device and run the `mount` command. Eject your USB device and run the `mount` command again. Compare the first and the second mount runs. Detect one additional line in the second run. The additional line should be something like:

   ```
   /dev/sdd on /media/your-username/USB2DISK type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
   ```

   In this example the mount point of the USB drive is:

   ```
   /media/your-username/USB2DISK
   ```
7. Click *OK* and then click *OK* again. Now the USB flash drive has been mounted so that Wine can use it.
8. Run Universal USB Installer.